# static_cast and reference to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, const-cast

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't compile:

```
struct A { };
struct B : public A { };

int main()
{
  B b;
  A* a = &b;
  B* &b1 = static_cast<B*&>(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Now, if you replace the static cast with:

```
B* b1 = static_cast<B*>(a);
```

then it does compile.

**Edit:** It is obvious that the compiler treats `A*` and `B*` as independent types, otherwise this would work. The question is more about why is that desirable?

Comment: `a` is not a reference to pointers its a pointer.

Comment: @MrLister `B*&` is a reference to a pointer to `B`.

Comment: FYI, dynamic_cast would be more safer

Comment: @user814628 Only if you do not know (because of program logic) that the cast is valid, and using `dynamic_cast` forces the compiler to embed runtime type information into that class hierarchy. Combine this with the relatively slow operation of `dynamic_cast` and it's a solution which you don't want to use unless it's necessary.

Comment: @user814628 `dynamic_cast` would not be legal here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`B` is derived from `A`, but `B*` isn't derived from `A*`.
A pointer to a `B` is not a pointer to an `A`, it can only be
converted to one.  But the types remain distinct (and the
conversion can, and often will, change the value of the
pointer).  A `B*&` can only refer to a `B*`, not to any other
pointer type.

Answer (score 3):

non-constant lvalue reference (B*&) cannot bind to a **unrelated** type (A*).

Answer (score 0):

Handling of references is something the compiler does for you, there should be no need to cast to reference.

If we refactor the code to:

```
B b;
A* a = &b;
B* b_ptr = static_cast<B*>(a);
B*& p1 = b_ptr;
```

It will compile.

Comment: I agree (see my post), but this doesn't do the same. For example, changing the pointee in ``p1`` doesn't change the pointee in ``a``.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to cast an `A*` to a `B*`. This is the wrong way around and not very useful. You probably want to store a pointer to derived in a pointer to base, which is useful and doesn't even need a cast.

I suppose a `dynamic_cast` might work here, but the result is implementation defined if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You cannot use `dynamic_cast` to convert a `A*` to a `B*&`.  It's not legal, and the code won't compile.

Comment: Casting from ``A*`` to ``B*`` is the only direction in which ``static_cast`` make sense. In the other direction, there is nothing to be done.