# C Style cast and C++ static_cast to reference of pointer

Tags: c++, casting, mfc

This is NOT C++11

I'm interested in the 3rd parameter of Microsoft's 
[CMapStringToOb::GetNextAssoc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hcw9z43.aspx), which has following definition:

```
 void GetNextAssoc(
   POSITION& rNextPosition,
   CString& rKey,
   CObject*& rValue 
) const;
```

Then I've got following easy code for testing: two good cases and one case with compiler error.

```
class CMyObject : public CObject    //in order to use CMapStringToOb
{
public:
    CMyObject(CString name_)
        :name(name_)
    {
    }

    void SayHello()
    {
        TRACE(_T("hello") + name);
    }
    CString name;   
};

void main()
{
    CMapStringToOb myMap;
    myMap.SetAt(_T("a"), new CMyObject(_T("aaa")));
    myMap.SetAt(_T("b"), new CMyObject(_T("bbb")));
    myMap.SetAt(_T("c"), new CMyObject(_T("ccc")));

    //good case 1
    POSITION pos = myMap.GetStartPosition();
    while (pos)
    {
        CString s;
        CMyObject* pMine = NULL;
        myMap.GetNextAssoc(pos, s, (CObject*&)pMine);
        if(pMine)
        {
            pMine->SayHello();
        }
    }

    //good case 2
    pos = myMap.GetStartPosition();
    while (pos)
    {
        CString s;
        CObject* pObject = NULL;
        myMap.GetNextAssoc(pos, s, pObject);
        if(pObject)
        {
            CMyObject* pMine = static_cast<CMyObject*>(pObject);
            pMine->SayHello();
        }
    }

    //bad case:
    //can not compile
    //    error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'CMyObject *' to 'CObject *&'    
    //        static_cast and safe_cast to reference can only be used for valid initializations or for lvalue casts between related classes 

    pos = myMap.GetStartPosition();
    while (pos)
    {
        CString s;
        CMyObject* pMine = NULL;
        myMap.GetNextAssoc(pos, s, static_cast<CObject*&>(pMine));  //compile error
        if(pMine)
        {
            pMine->SayHello();
        }
    }   
}
```

All I was trying to do is find an proper way to replace the C style casting to C++ style cast in this case.

Reading from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used), it mentioned:

> C casts are casts using (type)object or type(object). A C-style cast
>   is defined as the first of the following which succeeds:
>
> ```
> const_cast
> static_cast (though ignoring access restrictions)
> static_cast (see above), then const_cast
> reinterpret_cast
> reinterpret_cast, then const_cast
> ```

Q1: Was the above list missing anything (e.g. for rValue)?

Q2: What's the proper way of translate C style cast to C++ style cast in this case ? (good case 2 works, but, is there a more concise one?)

Q3: How is the C Style cast doing for rValue? (in other words, please explain why good case 1 works)

Comment: You need to use `reinterpret_cast` for reference and pointer types.

Comment: @paddy: "reference and pointer" mean "*&" ? In other words, are the following 2 statements corret?  S1: "You need to use reinterpret_cast for reference types."  S2: "You need to use reinterpret_cast for pointer types."

Comment: Yes.  What you have is a reference to a pointer type.  I just meant that for either references or pointers you need to use `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @paddy. In what context did you say "I just meant that for either references or pointers you need to use reinterpret_cast"? I've got confused in there is no constraints. static_cast<A*> or static_cast<A&> is definitely valid. See examples at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast

Comment: Your claim that you "need to use reinterpret_cast for reference and pointer types" is plain wrong, @paddy, in particular when it is made without any restrictions. You can use static_cast with pointers and references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `static_cast` between references (or pointers) to "unrelated types."  While you could `static_cast` from a `CMyObject*` to a `CObject*`, that isn't what you're doing here.  Here you're trying to cast a reference to a pointer into a reference to another pointer.  And the two pointer types do not have an inheritance relationship.

I like your "good case 2" code--I'd run with that.

For more details on the non-relatedness of your pointer types, see here: [static_cast and reference to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382730/static-cast-and-reference-to-pointers)

Comment: Great! I was fooled by the *& signature, I re-looked this one by **, then it is getting quite obvious. BTW, I've also post an answer to this question to explain this. Thanks!

Comment: It's usually a good idea to assert, that a pointer points to a particular type prior to performing a downcast. MFC's `CObject` implements the [CObject::IsKindOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7tsah76.aspx) function. Adding an `ASSERT(pObject->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyObject)));` before the `static_cast` is one way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to write that code would be to use `std::map<>`. Even if you insist on keeping the existing code mostly, consider fixing the interface of `GetNextAssoc()` to just return the pointer. In order to do that, you could simply add an overload of that function:

```
CObject* GetNextAssoc(
    POSITION& rNextPosition,
    CString& rKey,
) const {
    CObject* res = 0;
    GetNextAssoc(rNextPosition, rKey, res);
    return res;
}
```

Even more, you could template that function and do the conversion to the target type there. Also, you could then use `dynamic_cast`, which should be used because formally, the container stores `CObjects` and they could have various, different types.

Now, why did I partially ignore your question? The reason is that the MFC don't follow modern coding style and in some cases, they simply do things that are frowned on. There are a bunch of justifications for that behaviour, but foremost it is age (didn't know better, didn't have proper template support) combined with compatibility concerns (can't change that now). That's not a reason to repeat these mistakes though.

Comment: The idea of a wrapper function of GetNextAssoc is not bad. You might have to fix the signature by returning CObject*

Comment: Thanks, @milesma, fixed the returntype.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by John Zwinck, I will look from a different angle:

```
static_cast<CObject*>(pMine)
```

will **succeed** because type "CMyObject" generalize from type "CObject"; actually, this is done implicitly;

```
static_cast<CMyObject*>(pObject)
```

will **succeed** because type "CMyObject" generalize from type "CObject";

```
static_cast<CObject**>(&pMine)
```

will **FAIL** because type "CMyObject*" does NOT generalize from type "CObject*";

```
reinterpret_cast<CObject**>(&pMine)
```

will **succeed** at compile time because of "reinterpret_cast"; **how about run time?**

Let's make an assumption of the possible new implementation:

```
void CMapStringToOb::GetNextAssoc(
        POSITION& rNextPosition,
        CString& rKey,
        CObject** ppValue)
{
    *ppValue = (the pointer at the current position, point to an instance of "CMyObject");
}
```

So with calling this function by:

```
GetNextAssoc(pos, s, reinterpret_cast<CObject**>(&pMine))
```

the result is that "pMine" is pointing to an instance of "CMyObject";

So runtime is **SAFE**.

However, if we insert the key-value by (Note: CYourObject has no generalize relationship to CMyObject)

```
myMap.SetAt(_T("a"), new CYourObject(_T("aaa")));
```

and get it out by

```
GetNextAssoc(pos, s, reinterpret_cast<CObject**>(&pMine));
```

Compile time will still succeed, however, pMine is now pointing to "CYourObject", which will be **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR at runtime**. (static_cast has the same issue, though)